# I can't execute some commands in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using Windows 8.1, and I can't use some commands in PowerShell.

For example, commands about AD User (`Get-ADUser`, `New-ADUser`), or commands about certain Windows features (`Get-WindoswFeature`, `Enable-WindoswFeature`).

A lot of people use above commands, but I can't use them.

I don't know why it is. Please help me

Comment: Try posting this on http://superuser.com.

Comment: Install required poweshell module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell modules for those commands are not installed on client operating systems by default. You have to install the Remote Server Administration Tools for your specific client OS to get the modules.

Comment: So, I can't use some commands in powershell on windows 8.1 ??